# Compressed texture packer images caused crash in cocos builder

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, texturepacker, cocosbuilder

I have developed an animation app using cocos2d. Now i am working on compressing images. I have compressed some images using texture packer and got 2048 X 2048. I have change image pathes in cocosbuilder to this image set(select image from plist). When i am going to publish ccb file, cocosbuilder is crashing.

Edit:-
 This is what i got from crash report

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'ccbi export: Trying to write string not added to cache (animationCat.plist)'
Performing @selector(menuPublishProject:) from sender NSMenuItem 0x6000000add40
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Crashing how? Error message? Is CB able to work with TP's texture atlas format to begin with? From what I know CB may be trying to create an atlas of its own from the existing atlas, verify this isn't the case. If that doesn't help you should get the CB code and see where exactly it is crashing.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D . Could you see the edit for crash report details. thanks.

Comment: hmmm seems to indicate that CB is referncing the animationCat.plist somewhere but it's not internalized, perhaps not added to the project. Hard to say.